# Display all Categories except ones with a specific parent

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, categories, archives

I'm trying to display all post-categories except those who have an specific parent-categorie.

Can someone help me?

This is my current code:

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'  => 0,
) );

echo '<ul>';

foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';   
} 

echo '</ul>';

?>
```

Comment: Hello, There's nothing in your code which can say to WordPress to not display a category. You should give a try to https://generatewp.com/wp_tax_query/ which help you to write your correct Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`get_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) gives you an array of [`WP_Term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) objects, which has the `parent` property. This contains the ID of the parent category. Inside your loop you can do a simple comparison to see, if the current iteration category has the specific parent category's ID or not, and if it does, skip it.

```
$parent_id = 123; // change to actual term id
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
  if ( $parent_id === $category->parent ) {
    continue;
  }
  
  // rest of the code...   
}
```